# Get the name of all selected items from select multiple="multiple" options dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the name of all selected items from select `multiple="multiple"` options `dropdown`.

In my html page, I have the following code snippet:

```
<select id="ddlCategory" ng-model="myCategory.myCategoryName" multiple>
     <option selected="selected" value="1">Washroom</option>
     <option  value="2">Restaurant</option>
</select>
```

In my JS file, I have the following code snippet:

```
var categoryNameArray = $('#ddlCategory').val();
console.log("category = " + categoryNameArray[0];
```

However, the variable `categoryNameArray` only gives me the array of the selected items, what I want is the name of the selected items. Can someone tell me a way how I can make this work? Thanks!

Comment: What is the "name" of a selected item? Its text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `val` isn't giving you what you want, I'm going to assume you want an array of the *text* of the selected items.

You can get that like this:

```
var selectedTextArray = $("#ddlCategory option:selected").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

That finds all the selected items, then uses `map` to get the text of each of them (wrapped in a jQuery object), then uses `get` to turn that jQuery object into an array.

You can probably use `return this.text;` rather than `return $(this).text();`, since [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmloptionelement) has a `text` property (which most elements don't), but I'd be sure to test with my target browsers to be sure.

Example:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var selectedTextArray = $("#ddlCategory option:selected").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  console.log(selectedTextArray);
});
```

```html
Select some items, then click
<input type="button" id="btn" value="here">
<br>
<select id="ddlCategory" ng-model="myCategory.myCategoryName" multiple>
  <option value="1">Washroom</option>
  <option value="2">Restaurant</option>
  <option value="3">Service Station</option>
  <option value="4">Drive-Thru</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example with `this.text` instead of `$(this).text()`:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var selectedTextArray = $("#ddlCategory option:selected").map(function() {
    return this.text;
  }).get();
  console.log(selectedTextArray);
});
```

```html
Select some items, then click
<input type="button" id="btn" value="here">
<br>
<select id="ddlCategory" ng-model="myCategory.myCategoryName" multiple>
  <option value="1">Washroom</option>
  <option value="2">Restaurant</option>
  <option value="3">Service Station</option>
  <option value="4">Drive-Thru</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can I get the elements from selectedTextArray by specifying the index? Can I do something like this : selectedTextArray[0] ? It seems that I can't

Comment: @Antoni: Yes, you can. It's just a normal array. But when you say "elements," do you meant array entries or DOM elements? The array contains the *text* of the DOM elements (e.g., it contains strings).

Answer (score 2):

`val()` returns the values on the selected options, in your case `1, 2 ...`. You should use `text()` to get the names of the selected options. You can loop through all selected options using `each()` method and get the selected values using `text()`:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#ddlCategory option:selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    console.log($(selected).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlCategory" ng-model="myCategory.myCategoryName" multiple>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Washroom</option>
  <option value="2">Restaurant</option>
</select>
<a href="#">Send</a>
```

You can read more on how `val()` works **[here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**.

You can read more on how `text()` works **[here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var categoryNameArray = 
$('#ddlCategory option:selected').map(function(){
    return this.text;
}).get();
console.log("category = " + categoryNameArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ddlCategory" ng-model="myCategory.myCategoryName" multiple>
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Washroom</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="2">Restaurant</option>
            <option  value="3">Coffee Shop</option>
            <option  value="4">Hotels</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get all selected value is  $('#ddlCategory').val();